# pymssql : Inserting mutliple values into a table

Tags: python, sql-server-2008-r2, pymssql

I am trying to inserting multiple values into a table but I am not sure of the syntax..
I am reading these values from an excel files...

```
import xlrd
import pymssql

file_location = 'C:/Users/praveen/Downloads/OpTransactionHistory03-01-2015.xls'

#Connecting SQL Server
conn = pymssql.connect (host='host',user='user',password='pwd',database='Practice')
cur = conn.cursor()

# Open Workbook
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)

# Open Worksheet
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

for rows in range(13,sheet.nrows):
    for cols in range(sheet.ncols):
        cur.execute(
        " INSERT INTO MONTHLY_BUDGET VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
        %(sheet.cell_value(rows,cols))) <---Getting 5 values from here as expected,but not sure how to map these values to the table values..

conn.commit()
```

Problem :

I am inserting 5 values at a time and those values are coming properly from (sheet.cell_value(rows,cols))) like this :

```
31/12/2014  147801503777:Int.Pd:30-06-2014 to 30-12-2014    -   860.00  20,458.74
```

but in this case , the arguments number are not matching.. so i am getting an error :

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Table Structure :

```
CREATE TABLE MONTHLY_BUDGET
(
    SEQUENCE            INT IDENTITY,
    TRANSACTION_DATE    VARCHAR(100),
    TRANSACTION_REMARKS VARCHAR(1000),
    WITHDRAWL_AMOUNT    VARCHAR(100),
    DEPOSIT_AMOUNT      VARCHAR(100),
    BALANCE_AMOUNT      VARCHAR(100)
)
```

Comment: You should probably provide more information regarding what data do you have in a regular cell and what data do you have in a cell that causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the call `sheet.cell_value(rows,cols)` only returns one value.

So maybe collecting the values could help:

```
for rows in range(13,sheet.nrows):
    arr = []
    for cols in range(5):
        arr.append(sheet.cell_value(rows,cols))
    cur.execute(
        "INSERT INTO MONTHLY_BUDGET VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
        tuple(arr)
    )
```

Comment: This is really slow. I think the question was asking for a bulk approach